# Сессии и авторизация

Tags: авторизация, сессия, php

Здравствуйте. Я делаю авторизацию на php. session_start(); нужно запускать только на странице авторизации или на каждой, где я хочу использовать проверку на авторизацию пользователя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На каждой отдельной странице. В самом верху. То есть, если у вас несколько PHP файлов подключается в один, на них на всех нужен ОДИН session_start

Comment: Спасибо, это как раз мне и нужно.

Еще вопрос, как мне задать переменную для проверки авторизации.

Чтобы на любой странице я мог сделать условие как if($user_exist){echo "Вы авторизованы";}else{ echo "Вы не авторизованы";} ?

Comment: Тоесть что нужно задать переменной $user_exist.

Comment: <code>
$_SESSION['user_exist'] = true;
if($_SESSION['user_exist']){
echo "Вы авторизованны";
}else{
echo "Вы не авторизованны";
}

Comment: Все, разобрался. Спасибо большое за помощь.